# can I turn off the .ivy cache all together?

Tags: ant, build, properties, ivy

Is there a way to tell ant/ivy to not use a local `$HOME/.ivy2` cache?

Comment: Same question twice from the same author. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934948/setting-ivy-home-directory-in-ant

Comment: @MarkO'Connor - the other question asks about using a different location.  This one asks about turning it off completely.

Comment: In that case it's answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078774/is-it-possible-to-turn-off-ivys-cache-altogether/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [full book on ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/trunk/book.html), you check out the "Setting up the repositories" section:

> Several repositories use the same root in your filesystem. Referenced as `${ivy.default.ivy.user.dir}`, this is by default the directory `.ivy2` in your user home.
>
> Note that several things can be done by setting Ivy variables.
>   To set them without defining your own `ivysettings.xml` file, you can:
>
> - set an Ant property before any call to Ivy in your build file if you use Ivy from Ant
> - set an environment variable if you use Ivy from the command line
>
> For example:

```
<target name="resolve">
  <property name="ivy.default.ivy.user.dir" value="/path/to/ivy/user/dir"/>
  <ivy:resolve />
</target>
```

The packager resolver has also some settings to be configured to avoid `${home}`:

```
<packager name="ivyroundup"
         buildRoot="/path/to/my/.ivy2/packager/build"
         resourceCache="/path/to/my/.ivy2/packager/cache"
         resourceURL="ftp://mirror.example.com/pub/resources/[organisation]/[module]/">
    <ivy pattern="http://ivyroundup.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/modules/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy.xml"/>
    <artifact pattern="http://ivyroundup.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/modules/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/packager.xml"/>
</packager>
```

Comment: I am not able to get the user.dir to be set.  See posting at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934948/setting-ivy-home-directory-in-ant.  As far as the packager resolver goes, where is this file please?

Comment: Don't be distracted by the packager resolver. It also performs caching but one assumes you're not using it.

Comment: Be careful when talking about "user.dir". One would naturally assume you're talking about the current working directory property set by the JVM. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

Comment: figured it out.. I just had to add that entry to my common.xml file and not to the build.xml files.

Answer (score 7):

I'd create an ivysettings.xml file and specify the location of my cache using the [caches](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/caches.html) directive:

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="central"/>
    <caches defaultCacheDir="${ivy.settings.dir}/cache"/>
    <resolvers>
        <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

I think this more explicit and is less cryptic than setting the property **ivy.default.ivy.user.dir** within your build file.

## Update

Using this approach the ivy [cleancache](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/cleancache.html) task can be used to purge your nominated cache directory.

```
<target name="clean-all" depends="clean">
    <ivy:cleancache />
</target>
```

Comment: That's what I am also using but I can't seem to be able to `echo` or otherwise access the configured cache location (as a property) from my Ant `build.xml` file.