# Ant unresolved dependencies (hsqldb#hsqldb;1.8.0.10: not found) when building solr

Tags: ant, solr, hsqldb, ivy

My solr was building fine last week, but all of a sudden, the build is failing with the following:

```
[ivy:retrieve] Entry is found in the ModuleDescriptorCache : .ivy2/cache/org.apache.derby/derby/ivy-10.9.1.0.xml
[ivy:retrieve]  found ivy file in cache for org.apache.derby#derby;10.9.1.0 (resolved by public): .ivy2/cache/org.apache.derby/derby/ivy-10.9.1.0.xml
[ivy:retrieve] main: module revision found in cache: org.apache.derby#derby;10.9.1.0
[ivy:retrieve]  found org.apache.derby#derby;10.9.1.0 in public
[ivy:retrieve] Nbr of module to sort : 1
[ivy:retrieve] Sort dependencies of : org.apache.derby#derby;10.9.1.0 / Number of dependencies = 0
[ivy:retrieve] Sort done for : org.apache.derby#derby;10.9.1.0
[ivy:retrieve] storing dependency org.apache.derby#derby;10.9.1.0 in props
[ivy:retrieve]  resolved ivy file produced in cache
[ivy:retrieve] :: downloading artifacts ::
[ivy:retrieve]  [NOT REQUIRED] org.apache.derby#derby;10.9.1.0!derby.jar
[ivy:retrieve] :: resolution report :: resolve 1202730ms :: artifacts dl 0ms
[ivy:retrieve] WARN:    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve] WARN:    ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:retrieve] WARN:    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve] WARN:    :: hsqldb#hsqldb;1.8.0.10: not found
[ivy:retrieve] WARN:    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve] Nbr of module to sort : 1
[ivy:retrieve] Sort dependencies of : org.apache.derby#derby;10.9.1.0 / Number of dependencies = 0
[ivy:retrieve] Sort done for : org.apache.derby#derby;10.9.1.0
[ivy:retrieve]  report for org.apache.solr#example-DIH;working@L-SB80BEFFT4-M.local compile produced in work/projects/main/solr/solr-4.10.2/trunk-for-proactive-down/lucene-solr/lucene/build/ivy-resolution-cache/org.apache.solr-example-DIH-compile.xml
[ivy:retrieve]  resolve done (1202730ms resolve - 0ms download)
[ivy:retrieve] 
[ivy:retrieve] :: problems summary ::
[ivy:retrieve] :::: WARNINGS
[ivy:retrieve]      module not found: hsqldb#hsqldb;1.8.0.10
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== local: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    .ivy2/local/hsqldb/hsqldb/1.8.0.10/ivys/ivy.xml
[ivy:retrieve]    -- artifact hsqldb#hsqldb;1.8.0.10!hsqldb.jar:
[ivy:retrieve]    .ivy2/local/hsqldb/hsqldb/1.8.0.10/jars/hsqldb.jar
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== shared: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    .ivy2/shared/hsqldb/hsqldb/1.8.0.10/ivys/ivy.xml
[ivy:retrieve]    -- artifact hsqldb#hsqldb;1.8.0.10!hsqldb.jar:
[ivy:retrieve]    .ivy2/shared/hsqldb/hsqldb/1.8.0.10/jars/hsqldb.jar
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== public: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/hsqldb/hsqldb/1.8.0.10/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.pom
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== maven.restlet.org: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    http://maven.restlet.org/hsqldb/hsqldb/1.8.0.10/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.pom
[ivy:retrieve]    -- artifact hsqldb#hsqldb;1.8.0.10!hsqldb.jar:
[ivy:retrieve]    http://maven.restlet.org/hsqldb/hsqldb/1.8.0.10/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== sonatype-releases: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/hsqldb/hsqldb/1.8.0.10/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.pom
[ivy:retrieve]    -- artifact hsqldb#hsqldb;1.8.0.10!hsqldb.jar:
[ivy:retrieve]    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/hsqldb/hsqldb/1.8.0.10/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== releases.cloudera.com: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    http://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/hsqldb/hsqldb/1.8.0.10/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.pom
[ivy:retrieve]    -- artifact hsqldb#hsqldb;1.8.0.10!hsqldb.jar:
[ivy:retrieve]    http://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/hsqldb/hsqldb/1.8.0.10/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== working-chinese-mirror: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    http://uk.maven.org/maven2/hsqldb/hsqldb/1.8.0.10/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.pom
[ivy:retrieve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]      ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:retrieve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]      :: hsqldb#hsqldb;1.8.0.10: not found
[ivy:retrieve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve] :::: ERRORS
[ivy:retrieve]  impossible to acquire lock for hsqldb#hsqldb;1.8.0.10
[ivy:retrieve]  impossible to acquire lock for hsqldb#hsqldb;1.8.0.10
[ivy:retrieve]  impossible to acquire lock for hsqldb#hsqldb;1.8.0.10
[ivy:retrieve]  impossible to acquire lock for hsqldb#hsqldb;1.8.0.10
[ivy:retrieve]  impossible to acquire lock for hsqldb#hsqldb;1.8.0.10
[ivy:retrieve]  impossible to acquire lock for hsqldb#hsqldb;1.8.0.10
[ivy:retrieve]  impossible to acquire lock for hsqldb#hsqldb;1.8.0.10
[ivy:retrieve]  impossible to acquire lock for hsqldb#hsqldb;1.8.0.10
[ivy:retrieve]  impossible to acquire lock for hsqldb#hsqldb;1.8.0.10
[ivy:retrieve]  impossible to acquire lock for hsqldb#hsqldb;1.8.0.10
[ivy:retrieve] 
[ivy:retrieve] :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
      [ant] Exiting work/projects/main/solr/solr-4.10.2/trunk-for-proactive-down/lucene-solr/solr/example/example-DIH/build.xml.
      [ant] Exiting work/projects/main/solr/solr-4.10.2/trunk-for-proactive-down/lucene-solr/solr/solrj/build.xml.
      [ant] Exiting work/projects/main/solr/solr-4.10.2/trunk-for-proactive-down/lucene-solr/solr/core/build.xml.
      [ant] Exiting work/projects/main/solr/solr-4.10.2/trunk-for-proactive-down/lucene-solr/solr/test-framework/build.xml.
  [antcall] Exiting work/projects/main/solr/solr-4.10.2/trunk-for-proactive-down/lucene-solr/solr/solrj/build.xml.

BUILD FAILED
work/projects/main/solr/solr-4.10.2/trunk-for-proactive-down/lucene-solr/solr/common-build.xml:510: The following error occurred while executing this line:
work/projects/main/solr/solr-4.10.2/trunk-for-proactive-down/lucene-solr/solr/common-build.xml:421: The following error occurred while executing this line:
work/projects/main/solr/solr-4.10.2/trunk-for-proactive-down/lucene-solr/solr/common-build.xml:376: The following error occurred while executing this line:
work/projects/main/solr/solr-4.10.2/trunk-for-proactive-down/lucene-solr/solr/common-build.xml:396: The following error occurred while executing this line:
work/projects/main/solr/solr-4.10.2/trunk-for-proactive-down/lucene-solr/solr/common-build.xml:436: The following error occurred while executing this line:
work/projects/main/solr/solr-4.10.2/trunk-for-proactive-down/lucene-solr/lucene/common-build.xml:411: impossible to resolve dependencies:
    resolve failed - see output for details
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyResolve.doExecute(IvyResolve.java:333)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyTask.execute(IvyTask.java:277)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyPostResolveTask.ensureResolved(IvyPostResolveTask.java:231)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyPostResolveTask.prepareAndCheck(IvyPostResolveTask.java:178)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyRetrieve.doExecute(IvyRetrieve.java:87)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyTask.execute(IvyTask.java:277)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
```

I did do a git merge with the trunk to get my code up-to-date with the latest and no conflicts happened.
I have searched online for possible solutions and as suggested at some place, there is nothing wrong with my internet connection.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Removing ~/.ivy2 resolved this issue.

```
rm -rf ~/.ivy2
```

Comment: Another option is to use the ivy cleancache task. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019550/can-i-turn-off-the-ivy-cache-all-together/5023172#5023172

Answer (score 1):

Well you don't need to remove whole ivy2 folder. Removing the lock file will do the magic.

> **find ~/.ivy -name '*.lck' -exec rm -f {} \;**